# Added reference and using but type is not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, .net-assembly, .net-4.6.1

I whant override `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider`. In class library project I added reference on `System.Net` and `System.Net.Http`. Also I added using for this namespaces in 'cs' file.
When I'm write

```
public class MyProvider : System.Net.Http.MultipartMemoryStreamProvider`
```

The Intellisense doesn't recognise `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider`.

My class library project under is built with .Net Framework 4.6.1.

Also solution includes a web project with analogous parameters but in web project this problem is absent.

What am I doing wrong? And what assembly should be added to the class library project?

Maybe I must install `System.Net.Http` from NuGet?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have the correct namespace, but the [`MultipartMemoryStreamProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartmemorystreamprovider(v=vs.118).aspx) class is in the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` library, you need to add a reference to that instead.

Note the description of the class on MSDN says:

> **Assembly:**  System.Net.Http.Formatting (in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I'm not see this reference in Reference Manager. Why?

Comment: Look at question. I add screen.

Comment: Try [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/)

Comment: As I'm thought. Thank you!